# Asking for creating a bean of jpa repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

It is asking for creating a bean for the UserRepository class in configuration file. But UserRepository is an Interface which extends JpaRepository.
Error is showing that Create a bean of type UserRepository in your Controller class where i am using 
@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;

//my main class

```
package com.sumit.SecurityAttempt1;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

import com.sumit.Security.SecurityConfig;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.sumit")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.sumit" })
@Import(SecurityConfig.class)
public class SecurityAttempt1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SecurityAttempt1Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

//User Entity class

```
package com.sumit.DB;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    String username;
    @Column(name = "password")
    String password;

    @Transient
    String confirmpassword;

    @Column(name = "email")
    String email;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [username=" + username + ", password=" + password + ", confirmpassword=" + confirmpassword
                + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getConfirmpassword() {
        return confirmpassword;
    }

    public void setConfirmpassword(String confirmpassword) {
        this.confirmpassword = confirmpassword;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

//Repository Interface

```
package com.sumit.DB;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String>{
@Override
    <S extends User> S save(S user);

User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

//Security Configuration class

```
package com.sumit.Security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan("com.sumit")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
           http
           .csrf().disable()
           .authorizeRequests()
           // configure access rules
           .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
           .anyRequest().authenticated()
           .and()
           .formLogin()
           .loginProcessingUrl("/login");

}

}
```

//controller class

```
package com.sumit.Controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.sumit.DB.User;
import com.sumit.DB.UserRepository;

@Controller
public class BaseController {
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String first() {
        return "first";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/second")
    @Transactional
    String second() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername("1");
        user.setPassword("1");
        user.setEmail("1");
        userRepository.save(user);
        return "second";
    }
}
```

//pom.xml is here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SecurityAttempt1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>SecurityAttempt1</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Security Project Based on Roles</description>


    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-jasper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf.extras/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>

        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>

        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

//errors i am getting are

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-09-19 02:58:46.053 ERROR 15835 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'baseController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.sumit.DB.User
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sumit.SecurityAttempt1.SecurityAttempt1Application.main(SecurityAttempt1Application.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.sumit.DB.User
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1251) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.sumit.DB.User
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:552) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.11.Final.jar:5.3.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:74) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:201) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:151) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:134) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:65) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:305) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:211) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:121) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

Comment: can you post `com.sumit.DB.User` class source code?

Comment: @PiotrPodraza uploaded

Answer (score 2):

`IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.sumit.DB.User` indicates that `User` class is not not an entity hence is not managed by your JPA provider and Spring cannot implement the `UserRepository` for you.

You have to annotated `User` class with `javax.persistence.Entity` annotation to resolve this issue.

**Edit:**

You also have to instruct Spring where should it look for entities (so it can configure your JPA provider correctly) using `@EntityScan("com.sumit")` annotation, just like you did with components and `@ComponentScan("com.sumit")` annotation.

Comment: `***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field userRepository in com.sumit.Controller.BaseController required a bean of type 'com.sumit.DB.UserRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
 - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.sumit.DB.UserRepository' in your configuration.`

**getting above error**

Comment: And you still have `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.sumit" })` annotation?

Comment: oww sir,its working fine now after using  @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.sumit" }) thankyou  so much

Comment: I had a multi module maven project with entities in separate module, when add @EntityScan("ir.omidashouri.common.entity") above Spring Boot Application class, problem removed. thank you @Piotr Podraza